# TSS entries for stack switching

Tags: c, x86, interrupt, osdev

I have read that the TSS contains information about registers, etc. Right now, I am trying to implement the switch from kernel to user mode and back. I have read the the Intel 80386 manual, and was looking at this resource: http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev23.html for a general workflow. They do this:

```
void install_tss (uint32_t idx, uint16_t kernelSS, uint16_t kernelESP) {

    //! install TSS descriptor
    uint32_t base = (uint32_t) &TSS;
    gdt_set_descriptor (idx, base, base + sizeof (tss_entry),
        I86_GDT_DESC_ACCESS|I86_GDT_DESC_EXEC_CODE|I86_GDT_DESC_DPL|I86_GDT_DESC_MEMORY,
        0);

    //! initialize TSS
    memset ((void*) &TSS, 0, sizeof (tss_entry));

    TSS.ss0 = kernelSS;
    TSS.esp0 = kernelESP;

    TSS.cs=0x0b;
    TSS.ss = 0x13;
    TSS.es = 0x13;
    TSS.ds = 0x13;
    TSS.fs = 0x13;
    TSS.gs = 0x13;

    //! flush tss
    flush_tss (idx * sizeof (gdt_descriptor));
}
```

**I am confused as to why RPL = 3**

In my case, when I am in user mode and I want to use a trap gate to get to kernel mode, the cs segment in the trap gate would have RPL 0 (the last 2 bits of the 16 bit segment) and the GDT entry corresponding to the cs segment would also have DPL 0. And I've read that an inter-level privilege switch switches stacks (only??) looking at the TSS. I'm guessing that the above piece of code must have a TSS.ss = 0x10.

Note: We're assuming the classic 0x08 = Kernel code, 0x10 = Kernel data, .... GDT structure here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TSS structure has a lot of fields that are used for hardware task switching (e.g. `TSS.ss`, which is where the `ss` register's contents would be saved/loaded if a hardware task switch happened), plus a few fields that are used for switching the task to a higher privilege level ((e.g. `(e.g.`TSS.ss0` for switching to CPL=0).

You're looking at fields that are used for hardware task switching (which typically aren't worth bothering with because it's faster to do software task switching instead); and I'd guess someone shoved some "hardware task switch compatible" values in there (even though they're not used) to avoid uninitialized values.

Instead, you want to look at the `TSS.esp0` and `TSS.ss0` fields of the TSS, which are the only 2 fields of the TSS that matter for switching to CPL=0 (and might be the only 2 fields of the TSS you ever use).